# Fluid arround an effector

Tags: mesh, particles, physics, fluid-simulation, collision

I'm trying to do a fluid simulation of a viscous liquid (not much, Diffusion exponent 4), but even with a Resolution Domain of 300 i don't get the fluid touching a steering stick (effector with a surface thickness of 0) (see image)

Does anybody has a solution for this.
[image]
Many thanks

Here are the Domain settings

[image]

[image]

And here the efector settings

[image]

Comment: I think it might still got to do with the resolution. Even though you are at 300 resolution, your domain appears to be relatively big compared to the collision object. The resolution is relative to the size of the domain, so the bigger the domain, the more resolution you need. Try baking a few frames with 500 resolution and see if the distance between the liquid and the object is reduced.

Comment: Please provide blend file so we can check it out

Comment: I guess @AlexandreMarcati is right, since your domain looks quite large compared to the effector, it might be that the resolution is still too low. Also the _Particle Radius_ of the _Mesh_ settings could contribute to this issue. Another thing is you could increase the _Sampling Substeps_ on both the _Effector_ and the _Flow_ objects. And/or set _Timesteps Minimum_ to 2 in the domain. If you don't want to test with a resolution of 500, try scaling down the domain closer around the effector to see if it gets better at 300.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback!. I have made some simulations with reduced resolution and it can see that the distance between the effector and the fluid is of the order of the resolution. I will try to do high resolution simulation this night and I will come back to you with the results.  Despite of this, the simulations were to put an example of viscous behaviour by showing that the fluid near the stick moves with it while in non-viscous fluid this does not happen.  My final conclusion is that the way that Blender simulate fluids, this is not reproducible. (I am wrong?)